# How to fix [metasploit] error: block in materialize': Could not find pg-0.17.1 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Tags: bundler, metasploit

I am pretty new to this. Im trying to launch **`metasploit`** framework on a Mac osx 10.9.5.

```
block in materialize': Could not find pg-0.17.1 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

every time is use **`./msfconsole`** thats what comes up.

**How to fix this?**

Answer (score -1):

Try to install pg separatly: `gem install pg -v '0.17.1'`